# Calculating width and height given image resolution using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, resolution

How can the width and height of .tff image be calculated or deduced given the resolution of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyQGIS you can do:

```
rasterlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("nh_68_5")[0]
 
x_pixel_size = rasterlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
y_pixel_size = rasterlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
pixel_count_x = rasterlayer.width()
pixel_count_y = rasterlayer.height()

print(f"Raster width is {x_pixel_size*pixel_count_x}")
print(f"Raster height is {y_pixel_size*pixel_count_y}")

#Raster width is 100000.0
#Raster height is 100000.0
```

[image]